# Dúvidas em relação ao PEP8

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação, pep8

Eu li o PEP8 mas não entendi muito bem quando usar 2 espaços em branco.

Eu devo usar 2 espaços para separar uma seção de `imports` de uma outra seção?

Quais seções normalmente um arquivo em Python apresenta?

Devo ter um arquivo com todas as minhas classes ou um arquivo pra cada classe como em outras linguagens?

```
import os
import random
import threading

import pygame

from classes import Carta


def main():
    pass


main()
```

Isso está correto? Dois espaços entre a seção de `imports` e a função `main` e mais 2 entre a função `main` e a chamada a ela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não são dois espaços, são duas linhas em branco.

A PEP8 não fala sobre a separação de `imports`, mas acho que só faz sentido separar todos eles do resto do código, então ficaria assim:

```
import os
import random
import threading
import pygame
from classes import Carta

def main():
    pass

main()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Pep8Import.py).

Mas talvez possa deixar uma linha só depois dos `imports`. Não vejo a mesma vantagem de separar tanto quanto é dentre classes e funções soltas.

Não gosto muito da ideia de seções. Mas é comum ter as importações, as funções soltas, as classes e até mesmo código solto que deve ser evitado.